# placing figures in a row latex

Tags: graphics, latex, subfigure

```
I have 3 figures that I want to place in a row. I trim the figures as original figures
```

have a lot of whitespace.
The two figures gets placed in a row but one figure moves to the next row. Is their a way to modify the code to place all the three figures in same row?
The code is as follows.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
    \begin{figure*}[ht!]
        \subfloat[\label{genworkflow}]{%
                \includegraphics[trim=20 40 50 30,clip, height=2.8 in]{./figures/fig1.png}}
    \quad
        \subfloat[\label{pyramidprocess} ]{%
        \includegraphics[trim=10 40 10 30,clip, height=2.8 in]{./figures/fig2.png}}
    \quad
        \subfloat[\label{mt-simtask}]{%
        \includegraphics[trim=30 40 30 30,clip, height=2.8 in]{./figures/fig3.png}}\\
        \caption{\label{workflow}The overall approach. (a) figa; (b) Workflow for figb; (c) Workflow for figc.}
    \end{figure*}
```

Comment: You should post this on [tex.se]

Answer (score 1):

Put all the three images as minipages in one figure environment without and empty line.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./figures/fig1.png}
\caption{genworkflow}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./figures/fig2.png}
\caption{pyramidprocess}\label{fig:awesome_image2}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./figures/fig3.png}
\caption{mt-simtask}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
\endminipage
\end{figure}
```